# Profiles with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

Tags: java, spring, spring-junit, springjunit4classrunner

I have two configurations for my TestSuite which provide a different beans for injection. This works so long as I set my profile with an annotation.

`@ActiveProfiles( profiles={"a"})` and `@ActiveProfiles( profiles={"b"})`

But I seem unable to set it from the Property Source file

My annotations look like

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AConfig.class, BConfig.class })
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
@TestPropertySource(locations = {"classpath:/application.properties"})
public abstract class AbstractTestIT {
   ...
}
```

And the content of `application.properties` is

```
spring.profiles.active="a"
```

And the results in an unsatisfied dependency

As mentioned setting with `@ActiveProfiles` as above works and the correct been is used.

It's almost as if PropertySource and/or TestPropertySource don't work with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

Comment: Tried using EL to see if you can actually access any of the properties in your test? That would establish whether the properties files are being loaded

Answer (score 1):

> This works so long as I set my profile with an annotation.

And it is expected.

`ActiveProfiles` doesn't rely on the `spring.profiles.active` property.

> ActiveProfiles is a class-level annotation that is used to declare
>   which active bean definition profiles should be used when loading an
>   ApplicationContext for test classes.

And the `profiles` attribute that is an alias for the `value` attribute needs to be valued with the profile(s) to activate for the tests

> The bean definition profiles to activate.

It doesn't use the `spring.profiles.active` property.

The `spring.profiles.active` property specifies which profiles are active in the overall configuration of the the application, not for the unit test context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My intention it to provide the default profile in the ```application.properties``` file and then when been run under CI override the profile with an env. How can I reach this same result?